# Excel Formula Slow

Tags: excel

is there anything i can do to further improve performance of this formula ?

```
=IF($A3<>"",IF(Jan!$E6<>"",LET(d_patt,IF(Jan!$E6<>"",VLOOKUP(Jan!$E6,SETTINGS!$A$12:$B$27,2,FALSE)&IF(Jan!$B6<>"",Jan!$B6,0)&IF(Jan!$C6<>"",Jan!$C6,0)&IF(Jan!$D6<>"",Jan!$D6,0),""),"ROT"&IF(LEN(Teams!$BHR4)>0,MID(Teams!$BHR4,MOD(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(Teams!$C4,I$2,"0000000")-1,LEN(Teams!$BHR4)/3)*3+1,3),"000")&IF(LEFT(d_patt,3)="OVT",d_patt,"OVT000")&IF(LEFT(d_patt,3)="SSI",d_patt,"SSI000")&IF(LEFT(d_patt,3)="SSO",d_patt,"SSO000")&IF(LEFT(d_patt,3)="SDS",d_patt,"SDS000")&IF(LEFT(d_patt,3)="HOL",d_patt,"HOL000")&IF(LEFT(d_patt,3)="LID",d_patt,"LID000")&IF(LEFT(d_patt,3)="UNP",d_patt,"UNP000")&IF(LEFT(d_patt,3)="FLD",d_patt,"FLD000")&IF(LEFT(d_patt,3)="MAT",d_patt,"MAT000")&IF(LEFT(d_patt,3)="LIS",d_patt,"LIS000")&IF(LEFT(d_patt,3)="CBR",d_patt,"CBR000")&IF(LEFT(d_patt,3)="ABS",d_patt,"ABS000")),"ROT"&IF(LEN(Teams!$BHR4)>0,MID(Teams!$BHR4,MOD(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(Teams!$C4,I$2,"0000000")-1,LEN(Teams!$BHR4)/3)*3+1,3),"000")&"OVT000SSI000SSO000SDS000HOL000LID000UNP000FLD000MAT000LIS000CBR000ABS000"),"")
```

i have this on a sheet for each day of the year x 400 people so 146k+ times. this is therefor taken up 80% of the sheet load time.

The sheet basically gets shift patters from Teams, check if there is any holidays, overtime etc from the relevant month tab and relevant cell for the day, and then will generate a code like below.

ROT080OVT000SSI000SSO000SDS234HOL000LID000UNP000FLD000MAT000LIS000CBR000ABS000

i have so far managed to make this faster by using the LET function, but not show if its possible to make any further improvements.

if you need an example file i can send this or upload somewhere, not sure if that is possible via stackoverflow or a preferred site to upload to.

Thanks

Comment: I can't help but think that a VBA routine would be faster, especially if the relevant data was loaded into a memory array and the whole sheet is processed at once (including disabling events and screen updates). There are so many embedded `VLOOKUPs` in each cell that are likely largely redundant - my guess is that you could use a `Dictionary` as a lookup structure to avoid the constant re-lookup that each cell's formula forces you to do. As it is, you're causing 1.75 million `VLOOKUPs` for the whole sheet.

Comment: The vlookups are addressed with the LET function, so from my understanding this is run once, assigned to d_patt rather than running every time its needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a shortened version of your formula to reduce the complexity of computations.

Instead of building the 'OVT000SSI000...' string one piece after another while always checking if the first 3 characters of 'd_patt' match the current piece, we can set the whole string with '000's as default and only replace the section that matches 'd_patt' (see highlighted elements in screenshot below)

[image]

Which results in the full formula:

```
=IF(LEN($A3)>0,"ROT"&IF(LEN(Teams!$BHR4)>0,MID(Teams!$BHR4,MOD(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(Teams!$C4,I$2,"0000000")-1,LEN(Teams!$BHR4)/3)*3+1,3),"000")&LET(default,"OVT000SSI000SSO000SDS000HOL000LID000UNP000FLD000MAT000LIS000CBR000ABS000",d_patt,VLOOKUP(Jan!$E6,SETTINGS!$A$12:$B$27,2,FALSE)&IF(LEN(Jan!$B6)>0,Jan!$B6,0)&IF(LEN(Jan!$C6)>0,Jan!$C6,0)&IF(LEN(Jan!$D6)>0,Jan!$D6,0),IF(LEN(d_patt)>0,REPLACE(default,SEARCH(LEFT(d_patt,3),default),6,d_patt),default)),“”)
```

If $B6, $C6 and $D6 can only be either empty or a numerical number, in other words, if they are never a letter or special character, the 'd_patt' function can be further shortened as follows:

[image]

Which results in the full formula:

```
=IF(LEN($A3)>0,"ROT"&IF(LEN(Teams!$BHR4)>0,MID(Teams!$BHR4,MOD(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(Teams!$C4,I$2,"0000000")-1,LEN(Teams!$BHR4)/3)*3+1,3),"000")&LET(default,"OVT000SSI000SSO000SDS000HOL000LID000UNP000FLD000MAT000LIS000CBR000ABS000",d_patt,VLOOKUP(Jan!$E6,SETTINGS!$A$12:$B$27,2,FALSE)&(Jan!$B6+0)&(Jan!$C6+0)&(Jan!$D6+0),IF(LEN(d_patt)>0,REPLACE(default,SEARCH(LEFT(d_patt,3),default),6,d_patt),default)),“”)
```

Comment: Ok, so it's correct that with the `LET()` function the variable is only calculated once. So improving the calculation of the variable won't help so much. Reducing the overall number and complexity of calculations throughout the whole formula is necessary.

Comment: Thanks Dattel Klauber, so the string is checking d_patt to see if its there, if it is there i.e HOL080 then it should be adding HOL080 else if nothing then it will be HOL000 this defines the whole string as shown above starting ROT,

Comment: Hey jynxy, that makes a big difference. I completely changed the answer above. Have a look and let me know if that works. I hope I didn't miss any brackets since I couldn't test it in excel myself.

Comment: Thanks, that has worked, i have not had chance yet to check performance wise, but thanks for your help.

Comment: Happy to hear that, although I noticed that there was a typo in the second formula. There was a $ instead of & between two elements. Just edited it

Comment: Yes i noticed that thanks